# How Can I Get My FDT 4.X Template To Work in FDT 5.5+?

Tags: flash, templates, installation, fdt

I was confident about making new project templates in FDT4.5 but I don't seem to be able to do the same in FDT5.5

Further - when I am creating a new project I am only able to see one project type (Web) in the new Project wizard when previous knowledge of how the templates work would suggest that there should be AS3, Basic, Flash Professional and Flex - see attached images.

Has the way that templates for new projects changed? Or are my list of options for new projects not initialising correctly?

You can see that I have attempted to add a new project type to my list (FlashDevelop-FDT Hybrid) which I previously was able to do for FDT4.5 allowing me to have source files in an FDT project that were set up like the source files in a FlashDevelop project. However as you can see from the screen shot my new FlashDevelop - FDT Hybrid is missing from the options for a new Web project - as are AS3, Basic, Flash Professional and Flex.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the version of the template is correct:

```
<version>2.5</version>
```

Otherwise FDT 5.5+ will ignore it.

Because templates and project types change between major versions, the best thing to do is copy an existing, working template and then add in the parts of the old one you wish to have.